# Fractional Area Calculation

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, postgresql, intersection

I have a file (in both raster and vector) of different districts in a country.
I have also made a grid of 1 deg * 1 deg (both vector and raster) of the country.
I want to calculate the area of each district coming under each grid cell.

Eg: Suppose a district named A is distributed over 4 (G1,G2,G3,G4) grid cells. I want to calculate how much area of A falls under G1,G2,G3,G4.

Comment: You have tagged this question with qgis, arcgis-desktop, and postgresql.  Does that mean you are comfortable with a solution in any of these programs?

Comment: There are at least a dozen versions of this question already on the site - if you specify a particular software we can point you to an appropriate match, or you can search on "area overlapping polygons" (or intersecting polygons) plus a software name. Using your vector layers and Intersect or Union followed by some sort of summary statistic calculation or dissolve is the basic answer.

Answer (score 2):

Vector solution:

Intersect or Union the two layers. Both functions should be available in all three of the softwares you have tagged. Note that Intersect returns *only* the areas of overlap, while Union returns both areas of overlap and areas that are one layer and not the other. Hence Union will allow your results to total 100% of inputs, while Intersect may not.

The resulting layer of either operation will contain polygons AG1, AG2, AG3, AG4. You can then either calculate your own area field with a field calculator or rely on the system tracked shape_area field, depending on your data format.